# Profile and contribution forms aren't displayed

Tags: profile, joomla, contributions, permissions

I'm setting up a new Civicrm on a Joomla site, and I can't get the profile creation or contribution forms to display. I'm not seeing any errors, there's just nothing there. My guess is that it's a permissions issue, but everthing seems reasonable. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: When you say "nothing there", do you mean the entire page is blank, or are the menus and sidebars etc there but not the middle content? If the former, then check the web server logs (e.g. apache or nginx logs).

Comment: Sorry, I could have described it better. The menus, headers, footers, etc are all there. The only thing missing is the Civicrm content.. I tried adding event listings this afternoon and that shows up ok, but the profile and conbribution pages are still blank.

Comment: Did you sort this out?